# Grails <g:set> tag not executed inside custom tag

Tags: grails, taglib

I have a custom tag called `<mk:pageViewTag>` which first renders `.gsp` template and then executes its body inside:

Taglib (**UtilTagLib.groovy**):

```
string namespace = "mk"

def pageViewTag = { attrs, body ->
    out << render(template: '/templates/pageTagView') {
        body()
    }
}
...
```

Template I render (**templates/_pageTagView.gsp**):

```
<body>
    ${ body() }
    ...
</body>
```

GSP I use custom tag on (**test.gsp**):

```
<mk:pageViewTag>
    <g:set name="test" value="${1}">
    ${test?:0} %{--Here, I got 0. Variable test does not exist!--}%
</mk:pageViewTag>
```

Everything works perfectly except for `<g:set>` tag, which does not perform as I expect. Grails simply cannot see the variable I declare.

In the example above I declared variable `test` and initialized it with integer `1`. As an output I got `0`.

According to [Grails Docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/set.html) I can use `scope` attribute, and it solves the problem when set to `request`.

Are there any ways I can fix it otherwise? Why this happens?

NB: The inside of `mk:pageViewTag` is huge so I cannot just declare a variable anywhere outside.

Comment: probably timing in evaluation. maybe replicate what set does within tag by calling it from taglib?

Comment: @Neoryder Timing, perhaps. I wish I could do what you suggested but the logic underneath is not that straight-forward as I put in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect, but quick solution that does not require tricks (well, almost).
I execute `body` first and then I include it as template body.

**Taglib (UtilTagLib.groovy):**

```
string namespace = "mk"

def pageViewTag = { attrs, body ->

    // Render body ahead!
    String renderedBody = body()

    out << render(template: '/templates/pageTagView') {
        renderedBody
    }
}
...
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help, when using the render-tag directly from a view/template, like: `<g:render template='xx'><g:set...> ...</render>` and _xx.gsp: `<blah>${body()}</blah>` (see [GRAILS-4736](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4736))

Answer (score 1):

g:set needs a var attribute not a name: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/set.html

Answer (score 0):

```
string namespace = "mk"

def pageViewTag = { attrs, body ->
  out << render(template: '/templates/pageTagView', model:[body: body()])
}
```

**templates/_pageTagView.gsp :**

```
<body>
  ${body}
  ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I declared a grails variable inside a template and used it in the parent gsp file (where the template is included).

**Ex: Parent.gsp includes template: _child.gsp which has "`<g:set var="a" value="${1}" />`". Printing the variable 'a' in Parent.gsp renders a "null".**

Hence we found that while inserting templates with variables or set variables while rendering a template doesn't work. Because rendering a template takes time and is async with the Parent page.We can't be sure of the variable initialization until the rendering is completed.

***If the scope is set to "request",then we say that this variable should be visible for the whole request cycle and they are stored in the request for further process or access. 
Using `<g:set var="a" value="${1}" scope='request'/>` or `<g:set var="a" value="${1}" scope='session'/>`is recommended.***

Refer these links of how to use scopes:

[grails scope questions - page, request, flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273502/grails-scope-questions-page-request-flash)

[How to use grails <g:set> tag session scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143159/how-to-use-grails-gset-tag-session-scope)